# Java simple for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to find all possibilities to distribute n things to k containers. The containers all should have a different size so I made k inner for-loops for counting every possibility. Sorry for the bad explanation, but my english is not that good.

Now i need to know how to make k for loops so that it works for 2 and for 10.

Thanks

Comment: By writing the code to behave like that?

Comment: yes that's possible with java. you can start...

Comment: You can use a loop, inside a loop. If the outer loop runs 10 times, then the inner loop will be repeated 10 times...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you talking about running a for loop `N` times, or writing `N` nested for loops?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/? but they won't give you any java code though. Your (n,k) is pretty standard for a mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

break your problem into 2 steps :

1. get input 'times' from the user
2. run the loop 'times' times

   ```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter numebr of times:  ");
    int times = in.nextInt();

    for (int i=0 ; i<times ; i++){
      // looping 'times' times
      System.out.println("hello");
    }
   ```